# Trouble displaying an array of markers on Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have written a short script to take an array of location objects (generated by PHP) and plot them on a Google Map.

For the life of me, I cannot work out why the `addMarker()` loop breaks?

An example of an array I am sending to `initializeMap()`:

```
[
    {
        date: '08/11/2011',
        venue: 'Notes',
        city: 'Newtown, NSW',
        ticket: 'http://noteslive.net.au/'
    }
]
```

And the code:

```
// Accepts an array of gigs  
function initializeMap(gigs) {

var markers = gigs;

// Create geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

// Create the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gigpress-map"), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// Create infowindow object
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "holding..."
});

// Add markers to map
for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);

function addMarker(data) {
    alert('bang');
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data.city}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: data.venue
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

    // Bind click event to each marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}

// Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (index in markers) {
    var data = markers[index];
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data.city}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location));
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    }); 
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: where does it break? does it geocode successfully or there is not request going to the geocoder?

Comment: host the code on jsfiddle and try to reproduce the error there and update the question with the link

Comment: Yes it geocodes successfully. The loop does not complete. Bear with me, I am new to jsfiddle, I will host there now.

Comment: Here is a link to jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/KaSjH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the way you were adding the listener on the marker. I think I have fixed and I hope you can see your marker.. Here is the update to the jsfiddle you posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/KaSjH/1/

```
function addMarker(data) {
    alert('bang');
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data.city}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: data.venue
            });
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {  // Bind click event to each marker should be here. else marker reference not found.
            infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could [include the relevant changes in the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle).  If an external site goes away or even is just offline temporarily, it will be very helpful to have the key bits here.

Comment: anyways I think this was too specific of a question to be helpful to others.. thats why else i generally dnt..

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for adding the code anyway, though!  I do think it improves the answer.  +1

Comment: Thanks zzzz! You are a champion... Very careless coding on my behalf. Markers are now plotting although the fitBounds function is not working? In the loop I add each co-ord to the bound object. Here is a revised link... http://jsfiddle.net/KaSjH/2/

Comment: Trott, once I have finally resolved the issues, I will post a summary for any future users. Cheers.

Comment: So it appears as thought fitBounds is being called before the loop commences? I am so confused? http://jsfiddle.net/KaSjH/3/

Comment: please mark this as answer and ask another question.. I will be happy to reply.. post the questoin as a comment if u want to

Comment: Hi zzzz, thanks again for your assistance! I was able to resolve this over at Google Code... http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-maps-js-api-v3%2FGP4tZLPt_vc%2Fdiscussion

Answer (score 0):

For the complete working script head over to JSFiddle... This code will help you plot an array of markers and adjust the viewing boundary of the map.

http://jsfiddle.net/KaSjH/6/